# NPM logs on windows?

Tags: npm

I am trying to debug an issue with npm itself - it seems to hang.

Where does npm store its logs by default on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by adding the `--loglevel verbose` option to your `npm` invocation. Then according to the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel)

> On failure, all logs are written to **npm-debug.log in the current working directory.**

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following command in a command prompt to find where .npm is located in your windows environment

```
npm config get cache
```

Which should give you the location on your local machine where **.npm** is located, such as:

```
Directory of C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
 12/30/2021  01:12 PM    <DIR>          .
 12/30/2021  01:12 PM    <DIR>          ..
 12/30/2021  12:53 PM    <DIR>          _logs
```

**_logs** should contains the debug logs that you're looking for

***Note**: if you're looking for npm log location inside of a docker container then simply run that same command `npm config get cache` from **within** the container to get the location of those log files

https://docs.npmjs.com/generating-and-locating-npm-debug.log-files

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\users\<account>\appdata\roaming\npm-cache\_logs
```